# PHP - Unable to use data from database & Internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a website (similar to pastebin) that allows a user to submit text on the homepage, which then takes them to a randomly generated url (*domain.com/ABCXYZ*) that is running *run.php*, which will then display the original content they submitted.

Once a user submits the form their input `userentry` is added to the database (column `userinput`). The randomly generated url code `idgen` (so a random code like `KmdpV`) is added to the `randomurl` column in the database.

This much is working without issue (successfully takes users to a randomly generated URL and the adds the `userentry` and `idgen` to the database.

However, two issues are popping up that I can't seem to solve:-

1. I keep getting a 500 internal server error (seems to be caused by something within the `else if (isset...)` statement in the *run.php* code below. The error it keeps giving is `GET http://example.com/WsnNp 500 (Internal Server Error)` (where `WsnNp` is any randomly generate code) `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.
2. For some reason, I can't seem to access the `userentry` data at all. Once the form is submitted, it is succesfully added to the database and succesfully takes me to a random url running *run.php*, but it won't display anything if I write `<?php echo $_GET['userentry'] ?> (nor using POST, nor using SELECT ... FROM database etc.)`.

Being able to access the `userentry` on the randomly generated page is key for the entire site. The `userinput` needs to be permenantly available on that randomly generated URL, so for example, if I have the database row:

`ID | userinput   | randurl |
102 | Hello world |  GdksQ  |`

Then I'm trying to make it so that if a user visits `example.com/GdksQ` then it would display `Hello world`

I've already attempted grabbing the data from the database etc., but all my attempts seem to lead back to the 500 internal server error.

```
<?php $endurl = $_POST['idgen']; ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['userentry'])) { 
    // servername, username, password, dbname here
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO mydatabasename (userinput,randurl)
    VALUES ('$_POST[userentry]','$_POST[idgen]')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();  
    header('Location: http://example.com/'.$endurl);
}
```

The `if` part of this statement (above) *seems* to be working, because as mentioned, it does insert the values into the database, and it does take you to a random url after you submit the form (but I still can't display `userentry` nor `idgen`, even if I write it outside of this statement.

```
else if (isset($_GET['idgen'])) {
    // servername, username, password, dbname here
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT userinput FROM mydatabasename WHERE randurl = '".$_GET[idgen]."'";

    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
            if ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            echo($row['userinput']); }
        $result->close() ; }
  $conn->close(); } ?>
```

As far as I've been able to narrow it down, it's the above `else if` statement that's causing the 500 internal server error. Although I'm not sure if this is also what's preventing me from displaying / using the `userinput`?

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="idgen" value="<?php echo $randomGen ?>">
    <input type="text" name="userentry">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

($randomGen is just a function that generates a random 5 letter id for use in the url)

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ run.php?idgen=$1 [L]
```

This is the RewriteRule that allows me to use random urls and still run *run.php* on those pages.

EDIT:

Having checked the error logs, it seems the issue is stemming from this line:
`$result = $db->query($sql);` as it says `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on null in /home/mycpanelname/public_html/run.php on line 46`.

There's also some `PHP Notices`, but mainly seem to be undefined variables etc.

Comment: Check your server error logs for the reason behind the 500 error.

Comment: @aynber Good idea. Assuming the `PHP notices` aren't causing the 500 error, then it's likely this? `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on null in /home/cpanelname/public_html/run.php on line 46` Line 46 being: `$result = $db->query($sql);`

Comment: That would be it. Your query failed, or occasionally fails. It could be because you don't have quotes when you're attempting to access your `$_GET` (generating the notice about an undefined constant, use `$_GET['idgen']` instead). You're also wide open for SQL injection, and you should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, even though the previous comment is valid. Your db connection has failed. Make sure it exists and has connected successfully before you try to query it. Also, $conn != $db.

Comment: Are you sure it's an issue of the connection failing? The reason I ask is because I use the same code to connect to the database in the `else if` section as I did in the `if` section, and the `if` section must be connecting right? Because it successfully adds the input and url to the database.

Comment: The issue is that `$db` is null. In some cases, it's because the connection failed. In this case, it's because you set it the database connection to be `$conn`, not `$db`.

Comment: Oh right, so `$result = $db->query($sql);` should be changed to `$result = $conn->query($sql);`, and `$db` shouldn't be included at all?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have solved one `PHP Fatal error`, however it's brought up a new one. `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/mycpanelname/public_html/run.php on line 50` caused by `if ($result) { if ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { echo($row['userinput']);}` Seemingly an issue with the datatype? Is there anyway I can still display the result grabbed from the database without running into this issue?

Comment: You're using `fetch_object`, so either change it to `fetch_array` or change your echoing to use the object type (`$row->userinput`)

Comment: You're awesome, thank you so much!